# Why "broadband" has "band" in the name, when it's talking about signal?

Tags: word-meaning

In my native language, "band" is translated as "ribbon", and it's absorbed as such. So I just read a weird headline, translated as "The Ultra Wide Broad Ribbon is Still not Fully Supported". I tried to browse for the meaning of "band" but I can only find meaning such as material to tie/put around something (hence "Ribbon"), or the music band.

Comment: I suggest you need a better dictionary. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/band) has *3.1 A range of frequencies or wavelengths in a spectrum*, under the broader entry *3.0 A range of values or a specified category within a series.*

Comment: The word comes from radio terminology, and existed long before the internet - specifically broadband radio, the "band" here  refers to a range of radio frequencies.

Comment: See this entry in the OED: [**band** sense 14](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00017158)

Comment: As for the translation issue, this is the kind of thing that happens when people use google translate. It's often hilarious!!